# karate.abort() in v0.9.4 results in Failed scenario in cucumber html reports

Tags: karate

karate.abort() results in skipped steps. There was a fix previous for this . However, cucumber reporting treats skipped tests as Failed.

Is there any workaround where I can use karate.abort() and not have Failed scenario, as I am using it deliberately to skip some DB checks.

Or is there any alternative to karate.abort()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we need some community help to resolve how third party reports treat `skipped` steps, please read this - and maybe you can be the one to find a solution: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/755#issuecomment-488710450

A workaround is to split into a second feature and then:

```
* if (condition) karate.call('second.feature')
```

Comment: thanks Peter. After lot of searching, I downgraded cucumber-reporting version to 2.8.0 as this one has status flags. They were removed in later versions.
 Following command helps:
config.setStatusFlags(false,false,false);

Comment: @shrik18 can you try Karate 0.9.5.RC1 (beta) - it should be fixed https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/755

Comment: sorry for the delay. I verify this fix. Skipped steps results in Passed. in 0.9.5RC1. Thanks great work.